# ng-repeat loops too many times

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

For some unknown reason ng-repeat repeats too many times in the template file loaded from the ng-route:

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/items/item1', {
        templateUrl: 'items/item-review.html',
        controller: 'ItemController',
        controllerAs: 'myCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="reviewItem" ng-repeat="reviewItem in myCtrl.prop">

    <div class="row">
      <div>{{reviewItem.name}} </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

It gives me 5 loops instead of the amount of objects in the array that has 2 objects in json file:

```
[{
    "item": {
        "name": "content",
        "name2": "content2"
    }
}, {
    "item": {
        "name": "content",
        "name2": "content2"
    }
}]
```

The controller goes like this:

```
angular.module('dbreviewsApp')
  .controller('ItemController', function($scope, $http) {

    var myCtrl = this;
    myCtrl.prop=[];

        $http.get('items.json')
        .then(function(response) {

            myCtrl.prop = response;

        }, function(response) {

            //Second function handles error but there is no error during the get request

        });

});
```

Comment: remove myCtrl.prop=[]; and try

Comment: please provide a fiddle. What do you mean by "ng-repeat loops too many times" and "5 loops" ??

Comment: From what you have given here, there are 2 things which you need to change...change `myCtrl` to `$scope.myCtrl` and in HTML change `{{reviewItem.name}}` to `{{reviewItem.item.name}}`. How do you know it loops 5 times when it should not loop even once without these changes?. Please provide a fiddle or post your complete code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the technique you are using to assign back the response data:

```
$http.get('items.json')
        .then(function(response) {

            myCtrl.prop = response; //<-- This is the problem.

            // Comment/remove the upper line and write it like
            myCtrl.prop = response.data;  // <-- Correct technique.

        }, function(response) {

            //Second function handles error but there is no error during the get request

        });
```

Instead of `myCtrl.prop = response;`, use the `data` property to assign the value; like `myCtrl.prop = response.data;`

And to clarify why your `ng-repeat` is looping for 5 times is because the `response` object contains 5 properties namely `data, status, headers, config, statusText`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `myCtrl.prop = response;` it should be `myCtrl.prop = response.data;`.
Please find the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xU5T7R54mw1RxgxLxPDQ?p=preview)

```
  var myCtrl = this;
  myCtrl.prop = [];

  $http.get('items.json')
    .then(function(response) {

      myCtrl.prop = response.data;
      console.log(myCtrl.prop);

    }, function(response) {

      //Second function handles error but there is no error during the get request

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use $resource then data in response but if you use $http then data in your response.data

```
myCtrl.prop = response.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me troubleshoot.
Apparently the issue was in the passed object - by default it has 5 properties: `config, data, headers, status, statusText`, therefore the 5 time repeat, "data" targeting was missing.

Adding .data in the ng-repeat: `myCtrl.prop.data` solved the issue.
`myCtrl.prop = response.data;` is working as well.